# How would you map a derived class to its base class in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, automated-tests, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to build out a pattern for integration tests that hit the database in an Entity Framework project, and I'm having some challenges finding a seam.  Let's say I have a model that has may complex properties...

```cs
public class Sample {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* many other complex / required properties */
}
```

My typical test pattern would follow AAA:

```cs
public void Test() {
    // Arrange
    var sample1 = new Sample() { Name = "Test1", /* ... */ };
    var sample2 = new Sample() { Name = "Test2", /* ... */ };
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange(sample1, sample2);
    _context.SubmitChanges();

    // Act
    var results = _systemUnderTest.Act();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(results)
}
```

Because the entity objects are so complex it is an overwhelming task to configure all the entity-required fields.  Often all these fields are not required to be a specific value for the test.  So I'd like to adopt a pattern of using a derived class and a constructor, which then allows me to use object initializers and cut out a lot of the boilerplate.

```cs
public class SampleTest() : Sample {
    public SampleTest() { 
        Name = "Test";
        /* other default values and complex initialization */
    }
}

public void Test() {
    var sample1 = new TestSample();
    var sample2 = new TestSample { Name = "Custom Name for Test" };
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange(sample1, sample2);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    /* snip */
}
```

However, when doing this I get errors `'Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'TestSample'.`  I  understand the error message, but I was hoping there was a way to opt-out or bypass this.  I would like to identify a seam where I could instruct EF to treat all derived 'Test' classes according to their base class.

I've attempted ignoring the types in the `OnModelCreating` method which did not work.  I've considered creating a custom EntityTypeConfiguration which includes a mapping for SampleTest but I have not found a way to map back to the same table without a discriminator.  I've considered an EF Convention here, but I'm not sure if that would solve the problem.

I could attempt to implement it with a method instead of a derived class, similar to the following code, but I don't feel like that's as elegant or maintainable.  I'd prefer not to explore options along these lines.

```cs
public class Factory {
    public static Sample CreateSample() {
        return new Sample() { Name = "Test1" };
    } 
}

public void Test() {
    var sample1 = Factory.Create<Sample>();
    var sample2 = Factory.Create<Sample>();
    sample2.Name == "Custom Name for Test";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: EF _really_ doesn't play-nice with inheritance  - that's the heart of [the Object-Relational-Impedance-Mismatch problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch) and why so many ORMs look good superficially but fall-apart beyond simple 1:1 class/table designs. Now, are you using database-first or code-first? Are you using migrations?

Comment: "Because the entity objects are so complex it is an overwhelming task to configure all the entity-required fields" - you aren't actually "configuring any fields" in the code you've posted, do you actually mean _defining test data_? You do know there are tools for doing that for you, like Mockaroo?

Comment: @dai - We are using code-first, without migrations. True, I would be defining test data.

Answer (score 0):

**You're overthinking this** and consequently wasting effort. You shouldn't use inheritance simply to create objects with pre-defined property values for your tests, instead use a static factory method.

Instead of this:

```
public class SampleTest() : Sample {
    public SampleTest() { 
        Name = "Test";
        /* other default values and complex initialization */
    }
}

public void Test() {
    var sample1 = new TestSample();
    var sample2 = new TestSample { Name = "Custom Name for Test" };
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange(sample1, sample2);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    /* snip */
}
```

Do this:

```
static Sample CreateTestSample( ref Int32 id, String testName )
{
    return new Sample()
    {
        SampleId = id++, // Assuming this is your PK property
        Name = "Custom Name for " + testName
    };
}

public void TestMethod1()
{
    Int32 id = 1;
    var sample1 = CreateTestSample( ref id, testName: nameof(TestMethod1) );
    var sample2 = CreateTestSample( ref id, testName: nameof(TestMethod1) );
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange( sample1, sample2 );
    _context.SaveChanges();

    /* snip */
}

public void TestMethod2()
{
    Int32 id = 1;
    var sample1 = CreateTestSample( ref id, testName: nameof(TestMethod2) );
    var sample2 = CreateTestSample( ref id, testName: nameof(TestMethod2) );
    var sample2 = CreateTestSample( ref id, testName: nameof(TestMethod2) );
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange( sample1, sample2 );
    _context.SaveChanges();

    /* snip */
}
```

You can also use optional parameters to make it easier to override sample data defaults where appropriate, for example, supposing you have an entity `Person` with `PersonId`, `Name`, `DoB`, `StackOverflowScore`...

```
static Person CreateTestPerson(
    ref Int32 id,
    String name = null,
    DateTime? dob = null,
    Int32? stackOverflowScore = null
)
{
    return new Person()
    {
        PersonId           = id++,
        Name               = name ?? "John Smith",
        DoB                = dob ?? DateTime.UtcNow,
        StackOverflowScore = stackOverflowScore
    };
}

public void TestMethod1()
{
    Int32 id = 1;
    Person p1 = CreateTestPerson( ref id, name: "Matt", stackOverflowScore: 2223 );
    Person p2 = CreateTestPerson( ref id, dob: new DateTime( 1901, 1, 1 ) );

    _context.People.Attach( p1 );
    _context.People.Attach( p2 );

    _context.SaveChanges();

    /* snip */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests need to be simple, or else you could spend as much time debugging the tests as debugging the system under test. I would avoid creating a class hierarchy for this need.

Just write a method.

```
static class Utilities
{
    public static Sample WithDefaults(this Sample sample)
    {
        sample.OtherField1 = "Sample value 1";
        sample.OtherField2 = "Sample value 2";
        sample.OtherField3 = "Sample value 3";
        return sample;
    }
}


public void Test() {
    // Arrange
    var sample1 = new Sample { Name = "Test1"}.WithDefaults();
    var sample2 = new Sample { Name = "Test2"}.WithDefaults();
    _context.Set<Sample>().AddRange(sample1, sample2);
    _context.SubmitChanges();

    // Act
    var results = _systemUnderTest.Act();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(results)
}
```

Comment: In this solution, 'WithDefaults()' would run after the object is created, and would override fields any required fields that may already be set.  e.g. `new Sample { OtherField1 = "test value" }` which would cause complexity in the extension method.  I feel like this would be fragile.

Comment: Instantiating an object and setting its properties afterward is very common and I'm pretty sure your engineers can manage to work with code like that. I have trouble imaging the same of your idea, which is, frankly, bizarre. To fully understand the code, a developer will have to flip between the original constructor, your new constructor, and the test code. It is far less error-prone to just write a method. As for "elegance," I don't think unit tests are meant to be elegant.